# Webpack changing filetype and add class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to webpack and I'm using react slingshot as react scaffolding.

I have a requirement to change my script type to **"javascript/plain"** and add a class to my script tag.

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public'),
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```

When i use the above setting in my config page, output is rendered as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.d07bb7f51698832b7a13.js"></script>
```

I want to change the type to "**text/plain"** and **add a class** to the script tag.

Comment: It seems to be impossible mate. It doesn’t allow to do your weird case. But I’m not sure if you can write a plugin to serve your own case

Answer (score 0):

I myself had not done this, but use [HTML-LOADER](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/) , I think you can fix it with this loader in the webpack